# Is this question suitable for SuperUser?

Tags: support, questions

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/499190/how-can-i-find-my-linksys-wifi-network-from-my-iphone) was closed on ServerFault, as it's about a home network and not a professional-capacity one.

Is it suitable for SuperUser?

I got conflicting advice when I asked [on this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176504/why-was-my-question-closed-on-server-fault).

Answer (score 1):

Our [FAQ states](https://superuser.com/faq):

> not about […] smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer

As this seems to be an issue with your iPhone only, I'd suggest you post this question on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

You might want to give additional details of your router's setup and the iPhone model (and iOS version). As it stands your question is a little vague.

Comment: It's not an issue with my phone, it's with the router's configuration.

Comment: @HenriqueOrdine Do any other devices successfully connect to the router *or* also have the same problem?

Comment: I don't know, but I've already figured out the solution.

Comment: @HenriqueOrdine You're saying that your phone can't detect the network, so it's either an issue with your phone, or an issue with your router, but as it stands I would have suggested Apple.SE for it – is there anything speaking against posting your question there? I just saw someone else already suggested this on SF.